# Shell Script Read - check for enter key

Tags: shell, ksh, enter

I'm making a modular "menu" system and it's working so far.  I can use the arrow keys on my keyboard to navigate through the menu options, but where I'm stuck so far is detecting the enter key.  Once the right item is selected, I want the user to be able to press enter, then the script break out of the loop and act upon what the user entered.

But for some reason, I can read space, the arrow keys, and everything else, but not the enter key.  I've tried ''), I've tried "\n"), and all kinds of other things but nothing is working.  I'm using a case statement so I need a way in that statement to detect enter so I can break out of the loop and act what the user selected.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# Testing keyboard input using arrow keys
#
##############################################

clear

draw_menu() {
   clear
   echo -e "Test Menu (push X to exit)\n\n"
   i=0;ii=1
   for item in "${menu_items[@]}"; do
      if [[ $i -eq $selected ]]; then
         echo -e "< "$ii." "$item" >"
      else
         echo -e "  "$ii." "$item
      fi
      ((i=i+1));((ii=ii+1))
   done
}

# default selection
selected=0

# selections in the menu
menu_items[0]='First Menu Item'
menu_items[1]='Second Menu Item'
menu_items[2]='Third Menu Item'
menu_items[3]='Fourth Menu Item'
menu_items[4]='Fifth Menu Item'
menu_items[5]='Exit'

menu_size=${#menu_items[@]}

draw_menu
IFS=''
while [[ $t != 'x' ]]
do
    read -r -sn1 t
    case $t in
        A) # UP ARROW
            clear
            if [[ $selected -gt 0 ]]; then
               ((selected=selected-1))
            fi
            draw_menu
        ;;
        B) # down
            clear
            if [[ $selected -lt $menu_size-1 ]]; then
               ((selected=selected+1))
            fi
            draw_menu
        ;;
        C) # ignore side arrows
           clear
           draw_menu
        ;;
        D) # ignore side arrows
           clear
           draw_menu
        ;;
        '') clear
             print "enter key!"
             exit 0
        ;;
        *) clear
           draw_menu
    esac
done
```

Comment: You are matching on the escape sequence generated by the arrow keys as literal text? That seems fragile and a poor design. You should probably be checking the escape sequences that terminfo/termcap says will be generated and matching on those. That being said `read` like you have there only gets me the escape character in a quick test here. Also, is the `select` built-in not sufficient for some reason?

Comment: If you can read everything besides enter, why not simply make it the default case? - BTW I don't think enter can ever be detected, the read command strips it from the input.

Comment: If you must do it like this: construct a for loop iterating as many times as there are readable chars in the input string. You can get this information using `wc` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I decided to go with spacebar instead of enter.  I doubt I'll use this for anything important but it's neat having a pseudo-UI in shell.

Comment: @GordonFreeman What was wrong with the empty string? After all, that was a plain newline...

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the !/bin/ksh implementation of read.
When I only use "read t" without options it works for me.

Otherwise you can also try quotes on $t:

```
case "$t" in
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read  -n 1 key
echo "$key" | od -b
```

you can see the result like

0000000 177 012
0000002

where 177 is the ascii for "backspace" key

you can use these variable to define keys

```
esc=$(echo -e "\x1B")
enter=$(echo -e "\n")
backspace=$(echo -e "\x7F")
read -n 1 key
if [[ $key == $enter ]];then
    echo "entered"
fi
```

where 7F == 177 in 16 radix